# Python Socket: open connection and use it several times VS open and close every time you send something

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, sockets

Is it good approach to keep client connection open the whole time of the client session, or it is better to open and close it every time you send new data?

Comment: Is connection persistence a good thing when my browser gets the 3000 assets crammed into some blogger's WordPress site good? What about keeping my SSH session up because I might need it again in a week?

Comment: It's more rhetorical than sarcastic. To answer to your question as it stands: 'it depends.'

Comment: That depends so much on the specifics of the application I doubt there is one answer that's right for all situations.